# How to get pid of subprocess from the subprocess itself

Tags: bash, process

How can I get pid of a subprocess from the subprocess itself?

```
  foo()
{
 echo pid=$$
 echo spid=$!
 echo bpid=$BASHPID
}

echo PARENT_PID=$$
foo &
wait
```

on first run I get:

```
PARENT_PID=17112
[1]     17512
pid=17112
spid=
bpid=
```

I expect to see spid 17512

On second run I get something strange:

```
PARENT_PID=17112
[1]     17797
pid=17112
spid=17512 #why I see here pid of previous subprocess???
bpid=
```

I expect to see 17797 but getting 17512 !!

so 2 questions:
1)how to get the pid of sub process from inside of it (I will execute Foo multiple times and expect to see pid of every subprocess)?
2)why I am getting the unexpected result of second run?

Answer (score 1):

The POSIX standard defines that `$$` always is the pid of the main shell.

If you run a process in the background, `$!` returns the pid of the last background process.